# How to keep Email on GitHub private, but still make contributions visible?

Tags: email, github, push

I have an email which linked to GitHub account and I don't want it to be visible for people. So I set it private like this:

[image]

Having this configuration you cannot push changes with your email set in git.

If you set any other string as git email, it will be performed, but in contributions block there will be no contributions visible.

How to keep Email on GitHub private, but still make contributions visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in [Keep my email address private](https://github.com/settings/emails) line, you will see this comment:

> We’ll remove your public profile email and **use
>   25605156+yourgithubid@users.noreply.github.com when performing
>   web-based Git operations** and sending email on your behalf.

So if you attach this generated email to your git, changes will be pushed successfully, and you'll see your commits in contribution board.